# how to transform value string in object to new const js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json, object

i need to convert a object with have key value to new object that contain new const named form platform and have name to value in js how to do it?

```
posters: [
  { platform: facebook; name: ["user test1","user test2"] },
  { platform: instagram; name: ["Ig test1","Ig test2"] },
]
```

in to

```
posters: {
   facebook: ["user test1","user test2"] ,
   instagram: ["Ig test1","Ig test2"] ,
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your input array is invalid. There are no strings around your platform values, and you're separating your object properties with a semi-colon rather than a comma. So you would need to fix that in order to proceed.
2. It looks as if `posters` is a property within a larger object so this answer will take that into account.

Use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) on the posters array to iterate over the objects in the array and return an object where the keys are the platform names, and the values the `name` arrays.

Since it looks like `posters` is within a larger object we'll rebuild the object using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```js
const data={posters:[{platform:"facebook",name:["user test1","user test2"]},{platform:"instagram",name:["Ig test1","Ig test2"]}]};

// Create a new object
const updated = {

  // Spread out the old object into it
  ...data,

  // And replace the old `posters` property with an
  // object using `reduce`. Destructure the `platform`
  // and `name` properties from the object, and then
  // use them to add a key and a value to the initial
  // object (`acc`/accumulator)
  posters: data.posters.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    const { platform, name } = obj;
    acc[platform] = name;
    return acc;
  }, {})
};

console.log(updated);
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 0):

```
const postersArray = [
  { platform: facebook, name: ["user test1","user test2"] },
  { platform: instagram, name: ["Ig test1","Ig test2"] }
] 
const postersObject = postersArray.reduce((previous, current) => {
            return {
              …previous,
              [current.platform]: current.name
            } 
          },{})
```